# Fedora installed on USB drive boots from laptop w/nvidia card but not pc w/amd card

Tags: fedora, nvidia, video, live-usb, amd

I have Fedora 30 installed on a thumb drive which I use for work. I use it both on my home PC and my work laptop.

My home PC has a Ryzen 2600X CPU and an AMD RX 590 video card.

Recently my work laptop was upgraded from a Lenovo Thinkpad with no video card to an Acer Aspire 7, which has an nvidia gtx 1050ti video card.

Prior to the upgrade, I had no issues booting from the flash drive on either my home PC or the thinkpad.

After the upgrade, I was unable to boot from the thumb drive on the new Acer Aspire 7 until I installed the nvidia drivers for its video card. However, now that I have done so, I'm no longer able to successfully boot on my home pc. It does get as far as the prompt asking me for my password to decrypt the drive, however after I enter my password and it appears to spend some time decrypting the drive, but when it finishes, instead of presenting me with the login screen, I simply get a black screen with a flashing cursor at the bottom.

How can I get the thumb drive to boot from both machines? Is there a way to do it without having to uninstall/reinstall the drivers every time?